# When i was launching APK, I have got a error "keeps Stopping"

Tags: react-native

I follow this steps.

./gradlew clean

./gradlew assembleRelease

and create APK file.
But after launch my mobile.
I have error . **keeps Stopping**
[image]

Comment: run command in cmd  `adb logcat` and you will get the error in logs

Comment: You app is crashing. Attach a debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be something else that causing this crash.

- Open your Android Studio,
- Open logcat and check the errors

[image]

Comment: 2021-06-01 12:01:44.493 16747-18081/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
    Process: com.demoapp, PID: 16747
    java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10363 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2088)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
        at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.getConnectionInfo(IWifiManager.java:3503)